# Is there any use for RLIMIT_NICE?

Tags: linux, priority, nice, ulimit

I am using [`prlimit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man2/getrlimit.2.html) in Ubuntu to do some resource restrictions in my sandbox which has been very helpful. However, I am not quite sure what to do with `RLIMIT_NICE`. The docs say:

> RLIMIT_NICE (since Linux 2.6.12, but see BUGS below)
>                 Specifies a ceiling to which the process's  nice  value  can  be
>                 raised  using setpriority(2) or nice(2).

However, according to [getpriority(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man2/getpriority.2.html), a process can raise it's nice value only if owned by a superuser in the first place. But if this is the case, the `RLIMIT_NICE` value is not going to add too any functionality because a privileged user can arbitrarily lower or higher `RLIMIT` values anyway.

So I don't understand how to use or interpret `RLIMIT_NICE`. For non-privileged users the entire thing seems useless because they cannot raise priority in the first place, and it makes no sense to set it below the current priority. However for superusers it doesn't really add anything either because the `nice`, and `RLIMIT_NICE` soft- and hard limits can arbitrarily be raised.

So what is the idea behind `RLIMIT_NICE` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, `RLIMIT_NICE` allows you to bypass the basic rule that says that "a process can raise its nice value only if owned by root".

Demonstration:

```
# ulimit -e 30
# su nobody
$ nice -n -10 top
```

You will see that your `top` process runs with niceness `-10`.

Now if you try `nice -n -11 top`, it will run with niceness `0`, because `-11` is not allowed by `RLIMIT_NICE=30`.

The formula is given in the manpage: the maximal niceness allowed is `20-rlimit`. So:

- `0` means "you can raise niceness to 20", a.k.a. useless;
- `20` means "you can raise niceness to 0", which lets you go back to 0 if you lowered your priority;
- `40` means "you can start processes up to `nice -n -20`.

Comment: What is niceness in this context ?